How to edit the "new opportunity" button to only include necessary fields
When SRs enter information for a new opportunity, they have to scroll through 10s of fields that are left blank. How do I edit the new opportunity screen so that it only contains the fields I want it to.

There's a couple of ways to do this with varying levels of difficulty, depending on how much time you want to spend on it. You cannot modify the new button to show/hide the fields you want so we need to do this in other ways.
Way 1:
Create a default record type and assign a default page layout to it with the fields that you want. Hide all the other Opportunity record types from the profile so that they get defaulted to this record type. This is really handy if you switch layouts/record types based on the Opportunity stage, which is how I implemented Opportunities. You'd be switched record types for the new stage anyway so it's basically giving them a placeholder to get the fewer fields while they create the Opportunity.
Way 2:
Hide the new button from the account page layout and make an action button called 'New', then simply select the fields that you want them to fill out in the action. This requires that your users are creating Opportunities off the other records and doesn't really work for the new button on the Opportunity tab. However, it's a real quick way to declaratively select a bunch of fields for the user to fill out without having to make new layouts and record types. You can also default some fields if you wanted which could reduce the number of fields that they need to edit. You cannot override the standard new button with an action.. yet.
Way 3:
Override the new button with a lightning component. You can reference a visual screen flow or just build the page that you want with the fields that you want with the component. In this way you're basically making the page from scratch but you also have the most control over it. Want to give them the ability to upload a file when they are creating a new record at the same time, code it up. Want to do some duplicate checks where the user can select possible duplicate records instead, code it. Want to display some formula calculations while they are on this edit page, code it. Make it rain out there.

+1 for options; option 3 w/ Screen Flow is easiest for most admins and would be my choice; @LBBDS answer also useful though a maintenance headache

If you have dynamic forms set up for you lightning record page on Opportunities (which is totally worth it for a number of reasons), then you can set custom visibility rules for each field.
If you set a visibility rule for 'Opportunity Name not equal to [blank]', then those fields won't display in the new record popup (because the name is blank when the popup is loaded).
The answers above also work, and will give you a lot more granular control over what the "New" screen looks like.  But if you just want to hide some fields this will also work.
